# why does the -f switch of kaggle API download not recognize the file name passed to it as a string

Tags: python-3.x, file, kaggle

i want to extract a subset of image files from the kaggle dataset 'hpa-single-cell-image-classification'. i tried to use the kaggle API.
using the command below, when i download an individual image, it downloads fine,

```
!kaggle competitions download -c hpa-single-cell-image-classification -f /train/5c27f04c-bb99-11e8-b2b9-ac1f6b6435d0_blue.png
```

but when i try to pass it through a loop ( kaggle_img_names.csv contains the names of the images )

```
 with open('kaggle_img_names.csv','r') as fh:
        data=fh.readlines()
        data=[item.strip() for item in data]
        data=data[1:10]
        for file in data:
            print(file)
            !kaggle competitions download -c hpa-single-cell-image-classification -f file
```

'''

it shows 404- file not found .
I have realized that the with quotes at the end of the file name, the API says file not found

```
!kaggle competitions download -c hpa-single-cell-image-classification -f '/train/5c27f04c-bb99-11e8-b2b9-ac1f6b6435d0_blue.png'
```

how to pass the name of the file to the API such that the API processes it ? more than downloading the images i want to know why the -f switch of the API does not recognize the the string object (file name)  passed to it ? what is the type of the object passed to the -f switch ? is it something other than a string ?
Thanks in advance !